# Does Django or Bootstrap offer SelectOneListBox?

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I used primefaces before, and it offers a component called SelectOneListBox. I am now using Django, and I was wondering if Django or Bootstrap offer anything similar. I know Django offers the drop down box, however, I am hoping to provide a a list box where the user can see all the options and just click to select the item he/she wants.

Comment: What you are looking for is a simple `<select>` tag. Any multiple choice form field will result in a select unless you specify otherwise. I suggest you to follow a basic Django tutorial first before asking more advanced questions.

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap we can do like this

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <select class="selectpicker">
        <option>Value A</option>
        <option>Value B</option>
        <option>Value C</option>
        <option>Value D</option>
</select>
```

`
the first option will be selected as default.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option>option1</option>
  <option>option2</option>
  <option>option2</option>
</select>
```